# Sync two timers

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, synchronization, windows-forms-designer

I have a game that uses a shared disk to pass data between txt files, the problem is when i have 2 windows opened it's interrouptint each other and it stops working.

here is some code:

```
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (count == 1)
            {
                circle1.setX(circle1.getX() + (int)deltaX[0]);
                circle1.setY(circle1.getY() + (int)deltaZ[0]);
                File.WriteAllText(@"L:\achtung\player1.txt", String.Empty);
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"L:\achtung\player1.txt");
                StreamReader sw1 = new StreamReader(@"L:\achtung\player2.txt");
                sw.WriteLine(circle1.getX());
                sw.WriteLine(circle1.getY());
                sw.Close();
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                        x = Convert.ToInt32(sw1.ReadLine());
                    else
                        y = Convert.ToInt32(sw1.ReadLine());
                }
                sw1.Close();
                circle2.setX(x);
                circle2.setY(y);
            }
            else if (count == 2)
            {
                circle2.setX(circle2.getX() + (int)deltaX[0]);
                circle2.setY(circle2.getY() + (int)deltaZ[0]);
                File.WriteAllText(@"L:\achtung\player2.txt", String.Empty);
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"L:\achtung\player2.txt");
                StreamReader sw1 = new StreamReader(@"L:\achtung\player1.txt");
                sw.WriteLine(circle2.getX());
                sw.WriteLine(circle2.getY());
                sw.Close();
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                        x = Convert.ToInt32(sw1.ReadLine());
                    else
                        y = Convert.ToInt32(sw1.ReadLine());
                }
                sw1.Close();
                circle1.setX(x);
                circle1.setY(y);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, circle1.getX(), circle1.getY(), 10, 7);
        graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Gray, circle2.getX(), circle2.getY(), 10, 7);
    }
```

how can i read and write in the same time from two opened forms?

Comment: I ment that i have several computers that have same disk on them it called "L"

Comment: The problem here is not that the timers are interrupting each other. The problem here is that you're using files to communicate between clients. Set up a proper server version of your game, that is the only *real* solution.

Comment: Can't i do it without server? And if not how to set up a proper server?

Comment: "how to set up a proper server" -- to broad to answer here. Please do some research into the available technologies, such as sockets (appropriate for all kinds of network scenarios) or named pipes (appropriate for intra-LAN or inter-process-same-machine scenarios), and make an honest attempt to use available resources to implement something. If you have a _specific_ problem doing that, then please feel free to ask that question, with exact details about that specific problem.